# How can I filter locations by name in my db?

Tags: java, location

Im trying to gather into a list all the locations from my db that has the same name, in order to do that Im using this:

```
public static List<Location> searchRepe(List<Location>ls){
        List<Location>res=new ArrayList<Location>();
        for(Location l:ls){
            ls.remove(l);
if(ls.stream().anyMatch(x>x.getProvinceName().equals(l.getProvinceName()))){
                res.add(l);}
            ls.add(l);      
        }
        return res;
    }
```

ERROR:Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

I first remove the location of the list and then check if there is another location with the same name. After checking that if the name of the location is in the list I add it to my res list. In any case I will always keep the original list the same because after checking I read the element to the list. I know the error is caused because I remove and add in every iteration but if in every iteration I remove and then add the same element the size of the list will be always the same.

Could someone tell me a better way to do this? If it is possible using java8

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` statement uses `Iterator` to retrieve item, and `Iterator` can't remove item directly, otherwise the method will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. So you can remove item from list by following approach:

```
for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
    if(condition){
        list.remove(index);
        index--;
    }
}
```

In your problem, you can use `Multimap` which is a new Collection Type in `Guava` library, like this:

```
public static List<Location> searchRepe(List<Location>ls){
    Multimap<String,Location> locationMap = HashMultimap.create();
    for (Location l : ls) {
        locationMap.put(l.getProvinceName(),l);
    }
    List<Location> result=new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<Location>> entry : locationMap.asMap().entrySet()) {
        Collection<Location> value = entry.getValue();
        if(value.size()>1){
            Location next = value.iterator().next();
            result.add(next);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Pay attention to this line `locationMap.put(l.getProvinceName(),l)`, the result of `put` method depends on the `equals` method in `Location` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to use stream and java8, i believe this is right solution. 
Just filter all elements where count of occurrences based on `ProvinceName` more than one

```
public static List<Location> searchRepe(List<Location> ls) {

    return ls.stream()
             .filter(
                     location -> ls.stream()
                                   .map(Location::getProvinceName)
                                   .filter(n -> Objects.equals(n, location.getProvinceName()))
                                   .count() > 1L
             )
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

or by using grouping by

```
public static List<Location> searchRepe(List<Location> ls) {

    return ls.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Location::getProvinceName))
             .entrySet()
             .stream()
             .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
             .filter(entry -> entry.size() > 1)
             .map(entry -> entry.get(1))
             .collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: The first method works great provided that I wanted a list with all the locations that have their province name in common. The second method just gather the locations that appears more than once according to their provinceName. 
Thank you so much Neonailol